# Problema ao carregar arquivo de vídeo

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Estou criando um aplicativo para ver um vídeo em 360.
Estou usando esse plugin: https://cordovavrview.tangodev.it/

Esse plugin usa como base o Google VR View como base. Nesse caso ele tem uma função chamada `playVideo()` que recebe dois parâmetros: nome do arquivo e opções de reprodução.

Quando o meu vídeo está na pasta `www`, ou seja, quando compilo e gero o APK, funciona o vídeo normalmente.

Mas quando tem um vídeo que está na memória do celular, não está funcionando.
Estou usando o plugin do Cordova + Ionic (cordova-plugin-file) para pegar o arquivo que está na pasta Download.

Estou usando a função `checkFile()` para verificar se o arquivo existe. Se sim, executa a função `playVideo()` com o caminho do arquivo. Mas não funciona. O erro que dá é esse: **error while loading video**.

Parece que não funciona esse caminho, mas a função checkFile funciona. Já ocasionei um erro propositalmente e a função realmente funciona.

Será que é política de segurança? Não sei o que pode ser.

```
let path  = this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download';
let video = 'Video.mp4';

this.file.checkFile(path, video).then((data) => { 
   window['VrView'].playVideo(path + '/' + video, options);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Erro', err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema.
Instalei o plugin **cordova-plugin-whitelist** e coloquei no **config.xml** a configuração:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```